# Search for words in a string and replace only if there's a match

Tags: php, mysql, regex, loops, switch-statement

I've searched Stackoverflow far and wide and can't find anything relevant to my situation.

I have a booking confirmation letter which is pulled from the DB. the contents of the letter has tags, formatted like so:
|SURNAME|
|FIRSTNAME|
|TRAVELDATE|

and so on. These tags I have stored in the DB as well. What I want to do is, for each tag, find all occurences of that word and replace them with appropriate data for the particular booking, then move onto the next tag and do it again.

So far I have come up with (mix of code and pseudo code):

```
 function booking_Confirmation_Replace($conn, $confirmation_Email, $gp_ID){
     //Get all tags
     $tag_Array = array();
     if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name FROM Booking_Confirmation_Tags ORDER BY name")) {
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($name);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $tag_Array[] = $name; //For each tag it finds, add to the array
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }

    //Loop through each tag
    foreach ($tag_Array as $tag) {
        //find occurence of all tags in $confirmation_Email
        if (strpos($tag, $confirmation_Email) !== false) { //not working
            echo 'found occurance of word '.$tag.' <br />';
            //If there's a match, get appropriate data (possible with case statement) and replace tag
        }
        else{
            echo 'no occurance <br />'; 
        }
    } //end foreach
    return $confirmation_Email;
 }
```

I am unable to use str_replace() yet. If the tag has found a match in the confirmation letter, I need to do a call to the DB to grab the appropriate data, and then replace the tag with the appropriate data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work

```
//Loop through each tag
foreach ($tag_Array as $tag) {
    if(strpos($confirmation_Email, $tag) !== false) {
      // fetch appropriate data
      str_replace($tag, $appropriate_data, $confirmation_Email);
    }
} //end foreach
```

Comment: the strpos function is now working for me, getting one step closer! Knew I was on the right track!

Comment: In your example you have `strpos(string $needle, mixed $haystack)` when it should be `strpos(string $haystack , mixed $needle)`

Comment: I was able to fetch appropriate data using a case statement and replace the contents of the confirmation email. Cheers!